# Lateral location of the center of pressure

Tags: aircraft-physics

I am working on a simple flight simulator. For this, I need to calculate aerodynamic forces and apply them to the aircraft. As I understand it, lift and drag act through the wings center of pressure.

Unfortunately, all the information that I have found so far only talks about the location of the center of pressure in relation to the chord and the airfoil. Something like this:

[image]

So my question is, where would the CoP be located along the length of the wing? Say I model the aircraft as having two main wings, where would the lift force be applied? Would it be in the center of wing? I know that the location forward or aft on the wing depends on the airfoil.

Comment: [Center of pressure is more a mathematical construct. Aerodynamic center has a more practical use](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/97700/center-of-gravity-aerodynamic-center-and-center-of-pressure-how-do-they-connec/97714#97714). Normally it lies in the middle of the wing due to symmetry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is being referred to in the 3rd dimension is *lift distribution*.

This has several practical applications in wing design because torque stress on the main wing spar increases with distance from the center of gravity if 2 dimensional lift remains the same along the entire wing.

Some choose to taper the wing, as sea gulls do, to lessen the strain on the wing during, for example, a high G maneuver.

Another clever way is to ["wash out"](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Washout_(aeronautics)) the wing tips a few degrees, which, along with a little sweep, creates very desirable pitch stability up to and including stall, as well as creating the sought after "elliptical lift distribution".

*Both* wing torques should be identical (with respect to the center of gravity).  *Aileron* controls create an *imbalance*, causing the aircraft to *roll*.